# Do the electron pair in an orbital, have a net orbital magnetic moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, magnetic-moment, orbitals

It has been made clear to me that 2 electrons in an orbital have opposite spins, and hence their spin magnetic moment nullify each other.
But does the same happen with the Orbital magnetic dipole moment as well or not?

Do the electron move around the Nucleus in opposite directions in one orbital?

Comment: Spin (intrinsic and orbital) is a quantum mechanical attribute, so it is wrong to think of the electron as "moving around the nucleus" as if it's rotating around it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dr jh. sir, could you explain to me how an atomic dipole is explained by Quantum Mechanics, in not too much depth as I am a beginner.

Comment: Hi Akshank. I would love to. The comments section in these forums are not used to answer questions. Could you post another question and I'm sure many good folk here will be happy to assist you. Cheers.